# Batch file wont run in Task Scheduler in Windows 10

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-10

I have a batch file that run perfectly when you right-click it and run it as Administrator in Windows 10 however when I test the batch file and run it on demand from task scheduler it does not run. Essentially the batch file kills a couple of processes and launches MS Edge in kiosk mode to a python script which displays a timetable.

It does appear to run the taskKill commands as I can see MSedge and the script terminate but it never launches MS Edge.

```bash
c:
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application"
taskkill /f /im msedge.exe /T
taskkill /f /im python.exe /T
start msedge.exe --kiosk --no-first-run --remote-debugging-port=9111 --user-data-dir="C:\TEMP_DATA"
cd "C:\Program Files\Python311"
python.exe c:\data\show_timetable4.py
```

General Tab:

[image: general tab]

Action Tab:
[image: action tab]

Troubleshooting:

I have enabled run with the highest privileges in Task Scheduler.

Given full access privileges to all the process directory paths in the script.

The account that runs the task has full admin rights and the PC does not belong to a domain.

I have included a couple of images with tabs from task scheduler.

Comment: To begin with, your script should really have read as: **1.** `@%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /Im msedge.exe /T 2>NUL`
, **2.** `@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL`
, **3.** `@Start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk --no-first-run --remote-debugging-port=9111 --user-data-dir="%SystemDrive%\TEMP_DATA"`
, **4.** `@%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /Im python.exe /T 2>NUL`
, **5.** `@%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe /T 5 /NoBreak 1>NUL`
, **6.** `@"%ProgramFiles%\Python311\python.exe" %SystemDrive%\data\show_timetable4.py`.

Comment: When you selected 'Run with highest privileges' in Task Scheduler, did you understand what it meant? It's just you also said 'The account that runs the task has full admin rights'. The account which runs the task with that particular option selected is NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. It will also likely not show you the browser GUI, as the task should be run in the background.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply.  I will digest the script above and report back.   Ok so I shouldn't tick "Run with the highest privileges then and just select the account which is logged in with admin privileges? Could you also clarify what you meant by the last sentence? "It will also likely not show you the browser GUI, as the task should be run in the background" Thanks again

Comment: There is no graphical user interface available at all in the execution environment in which Windows services or Windows tasks are executed using the special account `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`. It is by design that all executables started by such services or tasks run always in background and can be seen only on looking on the list of running system processes in the *Windows Task Manager*. A graphical user interface is available only for applications started by a user account which is currently signed in. The *Windows shell* offering a GUI for apps is started on a user signs in.

Comment: Ok thanks for info.  btw your script runs fine.  I've only executed it directly from the batch file as admin but would like to know what the action tab in the task scheduler should look like for the following fields  "Program/Script:" "Add argument:" and "Start in". Thanks again

Comment: @RoyBreia Do you know the difference between `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /f /im msedge.exe /T` __with__ the option `/F` (and unnecessary option `/T`) and `%SystemRoot%\System32\taskkill.exe /im msedge.exe` __without__ the option `/F`? The variant with option `/F` results in a brutal __kill__ of all running `msedge.exe` processes __by the operating system__ without giving the *Microsoft Edge* processes the chance closing opened connections, finishing write operations to files/registry, closing all opened files and then terminating themselves.

Comment: @RoyBreia The variant without option `/F` results in `taskkill.exe` sends to all running *Microsoft Edge* processes the Windows [WM_CLOSE message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close) which is handled by all running `msedge.exe` with closing all currently opened connections so that the other side of each connection notices it accordingly, finishing all write operations to files or registry, closing all currently opened files and finally terminating. In other words the __TASKKILL__ option `/F` should be never used with *Microsoft Edge* (or any other web browser).

Comment: @RoyBreia *Python* is as good coded as *Microsoft Edge*. It also makes a graceful self-termination on receiving the `WM_CLOSE` message or the [CTRL+C and CTRL+BREAK signals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/ctrl-c-and-ctrl-break-signals). Running *Python* processes should not be killed by using __TASKKILL__ *with* option `/F` but instructed to terminate themselves using __TASKKILL without__ option `/F`. Most executables handle the operating system message/signals to close as that is what Windows sends to all running processes on a user shuts down or restarts Windows.

Comment: @RoyBreia I recommend reading the Microsoft documentation for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw). The task properties for the *Action* determine the strings passed to this function. *Program/script* is passed with function parameter `lpApplicationName` and should be in your case `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` as the *Windows Command Processor* is the interpreter executable for batch files.

Comment: @RoyBreia In a command prompt window can be executed `cmd /?` for getting output the usage help of the *Windows Command Processor* and which options it supports. The list of options and other argument strings must be specified in the scheduled task in the field for *Add arguments (optional)*. In your case is recommended using `/D /C "C:\data\startVDUv1.cmd"` as `cmd.exe` should be executed with ignoring the `AutoRun` registry value for execution of the batch file and then close itself. This string is passed with `lpCommandLine` to `CreateProcess`. Please use `.cmd` instead of `.bat`.

Comment: @RoyBreia The property *Start in* must be defined with the full path of the directory which should be the current working directory for `cmd.exe` on processing the batch file and which is also the current working directory for all executables run by `cmd.exe` by calling `CreateProcess` for each executable referenced in the batch file. The folder path must be without `"` even on containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` as that string is not interpreted by `cmd.exe` but passed directly with `lpCurrentDirectory` to kernel function `CreateProcess`.

Comment: @RoyBreia The batch file with the lines posted by Compo in the first comment works independent on which directory is the current working directory. The *Start in* property can be therefore also empty resulting in *Windows Task Scheduler* passing `%SystemRoot%\System32` as current working directory. But it could be that the *Python* script `C:\data\show_timetable4.py` is not good coded and requires that the directory containing this script file is the current working directory for working as expected. *Start in* should be better defined for that reason with `C:\data` to meet this expectation.

Comment: When there are this many comments, it's a sign that either the question is missing a lot of detail, or that the question is evolving into different topics. In this case, the second is what has happened, and you should stop asking additional questions in comments and instead use the **New Question** button to create a new post.